# Redirecionamento de URL Extensão Google

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extensão

Eu estou com um problema bobo, porém não consigo resolver.

Vamos lá:

Eu quero adaptar esse código

```
var pattern=/\bBloqueado/;
var viewtext = "http://www.google.com.br";
var newurl;
if (pattern.test(window.document.title))
{
newurl = viewtext;
chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: newurl});

}
```

Ele vê se o título da página esta escrito "Bloqueado" e se estiver redireciona para http://www.google.com.br

Eu preciso de algo que cheque se a Url é exatamente google.com e se for redirecionar para google.com.br e se for google.com.br pare e não faça nada.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que isso te ajuda:

```
var padrao = /^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(www\.)?google\.com(\/)?$/g;
var url    = "http://google.com.br/";

if (padrao.test(window.document.location.href)) {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect:url});
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde, pra que o Snippet se o código só roda em extensões?